# In label, value is not displaying which is used in module

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am trying to call a function (having two parameters) of module and assign values to it.
I can see the value being assigned in trace, but the same value is not displaying when it is assigned to label.

1. If I directly assign the value to label. It says:

   > Error:1009: Null object Reference
2. If I use `[Bindable]` meta tag to that label, it won't show any runtime error but the value is also not displayed. I have searched the internet and found that the `[Bindable]` meta tag works as try and catch blog.

How to get value display assign to label?

```
Main.mxml

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute"   xmlns:custom="com.custom.*" xmlns:local="*" creationComplete="onload()">
  <mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
    import modules.AModule; 
    import mx.events.ModuleEvent;
    import mx.containers.VBox;
    import mx.containers.TitleWindow;
    import mx.controls.TextInput;
    import mx.controls.Button;
    import mx.containers.HBox;
    import mx.controls.Label;
    import mx.events.CloseEvent;
    import mx.controls.Text;
    import com.custom.CustomAlert;
    import mx.controls.Alert;
    import mx.containers.Canvas;
    import mx.events.ItemClickEvent;

    import mx.core.UIComponent;

    import mx.modules.ModuleManager;
    import mx.modules.IModuleInfo;
    import mx.containers.Box;
    import mx.controls.ProgressBar;

    //private var can:Canvas;

    public var titlewin:TitleWindow = new TitleWindow();
        public var usern:TextInput = new TextInput();
        public var passw:TextInput = new TextInput();
        public var vb:VBox = new VBox();
        public var hb1:HBox = new HBox();
        public var hb2:HBox = new HBox();
        public var hb3:HBox = new HBox();
        public var nc:NetConnection;

        public var bt1:Button = new Button();

        private var pb:ProgressBar;
    private var progressContainer:Box;
    private var info:IModuleInfo;
    private var module:UIComponent = null;
    public var can:Canvas= new Canvas();
    public function onload():void
    {
            var label1:Label= new Label();
        var label2:Label= new Label();
        label1.text="Username";
        label2.text="Password ";
        hb1.addChild(label1);
        hb1.addChild(usern);
        hb2.addChild(label2);
        hb2.addChild(passw);
        vb.addChild(hb1);
        vb.addChild(hb2);           
        bt1.label="Sign In";
        hb3.addChild(vb);
        hb3.addChild(bt1);
        titlewin.addChild(hb3);

        //Title Window creation starts here
        titlewin.title="Login";

        titlewin.setStyle("paddingLeft",20);
        titlewin.setStyle("paddingRight",20);
        titlewin.setStyle("paddingTop",20);
        titlewin.setStyle("paddingBottom",20);
        titlewin.setStyle("borderThicknessBottom",0);
        titlewin.setStyle("borderThicknessLeft",0);
        titlewin.setStyle("borderThicknessRight",0);
        titlewin.setStyle("borderThicknessTop",0);
        titlewin.setStyle("cornerRadius",0);
        titlewin.setStyle("borderColor","#D20101");
        this.addChild(titlewin);
        viewStack.enabled=false;
        ctbb.enabled=false;
        bt1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, netconn);

    }

    private function onclick():void
    {
        if(usern.text!="")
        {
    this.removeChild(titlewin);
    viewStack.enabled=true; 
    ctbb.enabled=true;
    username.text=usern.text;
        }
        else
        {
            Alert.show("Please enter Username");
        }
    }


    private function netconn(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        nc = new NetConnection();
        nc.connect("rtmp://localhost/loginhere",usern.text);
        nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onstatushandler);

    }

    private function onstatushandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void
    {
        if(event.info.code=="NetConnection.Connect.Success")
        {
            status.text="Connected";
        onclick();  
            }


        if(event.info.code=="NetConnection.Connect.Rejected")
        {
            status.text="Rejected";
        }
        if(event.info.code=="NetConnection.Connect.Failed")
        {
                status.text="Failed";
        }
    }



    private function JoinClick(event:MouseEvent):void{

        if(viewStack.numChildren==3)
        {
            Alert.show("You Cant Add More Button","Alert");

        }

        if(viewStack.numChildren<3)
        {

        if(viewStack.numChildren<2)
        {
        can.label="Button2";
        var button1:CustomButton= new CustomButton();
        button1.label="Leave Table";
        button1.x=300;
        button1.y=200;
        var txt:Text = new Text();
        txt.text=can.label;
        txt.x=50;
        txt.y=50;
        button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,remove2);
        can.addChild(button1);
        can.addChild(txt);
        loadmodule();
        }
        else
        {

        can.label="Button3";
        var button2:CustomButton= new CustomButton();
        button2.label="Leave Table";
        button2.x=300;
        button2.y=200;
        button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,remove3);
        can.addChild(button2);
        var txt1:Text = new Text();
        txt1.text=can.label;
        txt1.x=50;
        txt1.y=50;
        can.addChild(txt1);
        }
        can.setStyle("backgroundColor","0x5EA5BA");
        viewStack.addChild(can);
        if(viewStack.numChildren>2)
        {
            viewStack.selectedIndex=2;
        }
        else
        {
        viewStack.selectedIndex=1;
        }
        }

        }


        private function remove2(event:MouseEvent):void{
        Alert.show("Do you want to Leave    Table?","Confirmation",Alert.YES|Alert.NO,this,closeAlert2);
        }
        private function closeAlert2(event:CloseEvent):void{
        if(event.detail==Alert.YES)
        {
        viewStack.removeChildAt(1);
        }

        }
        private function remove3(event:MouseEvent):void{
        if(viewStack.numChildren>2)
        {
            Alert.show("Do You want to leave Table?","Confirmation",Alert.YES|Alert.NO,this,closeAlert3);

        }
        else
        {
            Alert.show("Do you want to Leave Table?","Confirmation",Alert.YES|Alert.NO,this,closeAlert1);

        }
        }

        private function closeAlert1(event:CloseEvent):void{
            if(event.detail==Alert.YES)
            {
                viewStack.removeChildAt(1);

            }
        }
        private function closeAlert3(event:CloseEvent):void{
            if(event.detail==Alert.YES)
            {
                    viewStack.removeChildAt(2);
            }
        }


            private function loadmodule():void
    {
            pb = new ProgressBar();
            pb.labelPlacement = "center";
            pb.label = "Loading %3 %";
            progressContainer = new Box();
            progressContainer.percentWidth = 100;
            progressContainer.percentHeight = 100;
            progressContainer.setStyle("horizontalAlign", "center");
            progressContainer.setStyle("verticalAlign", "middle");
            progressContainer.addChild(pb);  
            can.addChild(progressContainer);


        var moduleUrl:String="../bin-debug/modules/useModule.swf";
        info=ModuleManager.getModule(moduleUrl);
        if(info!=null)
        {
            info.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.READY, modEventHandler);
            info.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.ERROR,modErrorHandler);
            info.load();
        }
    }



    private function modEventHandler(e:ModuleEvent):void
    {
        info.removeEventListener(ModuleEvent.READY, modEventHandler);
        info.removeEventListener(ModuleEvent.ERROR, modErrorHandler);
        can.removeAllChildren();
        if(module==null)
        {

            module = info.factory.create() as UIComponent;
            if(module!=null)
            { 
                module.x=0;
                module.y=0;
                module.percentWidth=100;
                module.percentHeight=100;
                can.addChild(module);
                 if(module is AModule)
                {

                } 
            }
        }
        }

            private function modErrorHandler(event:ModuleEvent):void {


            //cleanup and display an error alert
            info.removeEventListener(ModuleEvent.READY, modEventHandler);
            info.removeEventListener(ModuleEvent.ERROR, modErrorHandler);
            info = null;
            Alert.show(event.toString(), "Error Loading Module");

          unloadModule();
        }   
                private function unloadModule():void 
                {
           can.removeAllChildren();
            if (module != null && info != null) {
                info.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.UNLOAD,    unloadEventHandler);
                info.unload();
            }
        }

                private function unloadEventHandler(e:ModuleEvent):void 
                {
            info.removeEventListener(ModuleEvent.UNLOAD, unloadEventHandler);
            module = null;
            info = null;
                 }


]]>
  </mx:Script>

 <mx:Canvas width="700" height="400" x="166" y="32">
 <mx:ViewStack id="viewStack"  width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:Canvas label="Button1" backgroundColor="#5EA5BA" visible="true" id="can1" >
    <local:CustomButton label="Join" click="JoinClick(event)"  x="536" y="222"/>
    <mx:Label x="304" y="120" text="Label" id="username"/>
    <mx:Label x="304" y="55" text="Label" id="status"/>
    </mx:Canvas> 
</mx:ViewStack>

 </mx:Canvas>
  <custom:CustomControlBar x="166" y="423" id="ctbb">
  <custom:CustomToggleButtonBar  dataProvider="viewStack"/>
  </custom:CustomControlBar>

  </mx:Application>
```

useModule.mxml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <mx:Module xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" width="508"  height="218" implements="modules.AModule" backgroundColor="#F00F0F"  creationComplete="addlabel();">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.core.Application;

        public var logsin:loginhere = new loginhere();
        public function addlabel():void
        {
            lb1.text=logsin.username.text;
            txt3.text=logsin.username.text;
            trace(txt3.text);
            trace(lb1.text);
        }


    ]]>
</mx:Script>

    <mx:TextInput id="txt3" x="30.5" y="10" width="79"/>
    <mx:Label id="lb1" x="31.5" y="40" width="78" text="Will it Change?"/>
</mx:Module>
```

AModule.as (Its an interface)

```
package modules
{  
import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;

public interface AModule extends IEventDispatcher
{
    function addlabel():void;
}
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code you've used - this will make it easier for us to help.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Its too complicated to show as, as the code gets data from server and do the remaining operations. can you just help me with some sort of example, as 

i need to pass value to a function(having two parameters) in module from a main file and load the module. Thanks

Comment: Sorry @JcFx , I have updated my question, please let me know, if you dint understood my problem. Thank You

Comment: +1 This is now a good question. I can't immediately see what's causing your error, but hopefully somebody else will be able to help.

Comment: Is the problem in the Module.mxml? I see you create a new Canvas1 element there without passing on a new string to set as label for it.

Comment: Hello @Marjolein , i have updated my code, Please can you go through it.

I hope this will give a better understanding of problem, with no ambiguities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't looked through the entire code, but one thing I noticed is that you should pass the values on as parameters to the child components and use data binding to dynamically update parameters.

So in AModule.as:

```
<mx:Module xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" width="508"  height="218" implements="modules.AModule" backgroundColor="#F00F0F"  creationComplete="addlabel();">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.core.Application;

        public var logsin:loginhere = new loginhere();

        [Bindable]
        public var username:String = "";
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

    <mx:TextInput id="txt3" text="{username}" x="30.5" y="10" width="79"/>
    <mx:Label id="lb1" text="{username}" x="31.5" y="40" width="78" text="Will it Change?"/>
</mx:Module>
```

In the method where you create the module you can then:

```
module.username = //var that holds username;
```

Comment: The point I missed was, I dint create a var for interace
The var should be created in <br/> `modEventHandler` function <br/>
In that function the below line should be added
<br/>
    `ichild=module as AModule;
    ichild.addlabel(tt.text);`

so the module gets called and the value is displayed in the label field.

Please let me know, if its wrong way of working.

Answer (score 0):

The point I missed was, I dint create a instance for interface in main.mxml
The var should be created in  `modEventHandler` function In that function the below lines should be added

```
ichild=module as AModule;

ichild.addlabel(tt.text);
```

so the module gets called and the value is displayed in the label field.

Please let me know, if its wrong way of working. Thank You